# Is there a way to make a slide transition that makes the elements go below the border?

Tags: css, vue.js

Making a Vue app with 2 pages and I want to add a slide transition for my router-link where the elements slide under the border. Managed to make the slide transition but I don't know how to get the elements to go below the border. (The border is this case is the border for #app).

GIF of the current state: https://i.imgur.com/NKxM2Cn.gifv

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <transition name="slide" mode="out-in">
      <router-view/>
    </transition>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App'
}
</script>

<style>
.slide-enter-active, .slide-leave-active {
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
}

.slide-enter {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.slide-leave-to {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

#app {
  width: 750px;
  height: 920px;
  border: 1px solid #A9A9A9;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use to `overflow: hidden;` property on the parent element (`#app` in your case).

See this fiddle and play around with the `overflow` on the `.parent` class to get a better understanding of it:
https://jsfiddle.net/87rcf3vp/1/